# EF RemoveRange not working inside Transaction Scope

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, repository-pattern, transactionscope

I am using Entity Framework 6.2.0 in our ASP.NET MVC Project and in one of the operations we deleting a range of records from repository with the below code. We want this to happen under transaction scope so any error occurs it will rollback the whole transaction.

Below is my code snippet. The below code works fine if I remove the transaction scope but fails with it. We using the database first approach here.

```
 using (var tScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
 {                

     var boxes= _boxRepository.GetConditionalQuery(s => processId==1).ToList();
     if (boxes.Count > 0)
         _boxRepository.RemoveRange(boxes);

         var boxDeliveries= _deliveriesepository.GetConditionalQuery(s => processId==1).ToList();
         _boxDeliveryRepository.RemoveRange(boxDeliveries);

         _unitOfWork.Commit();
         tScope.Complete();

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What you mean by "fails"? Did you get some exception?

Comment: What is `RemoveRange` and `boxDeliveryRpository`? Why are you using an explicit transaction at all?? `SaveChanges` uses an internal transaction to persist all pending changes so there's no need for explicit transactions unless .... you break EF by using the "generic repository" **antipattern**

Comment: @faNot really the records are not getting deleted, Surprisingly no exception is thrown.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for enlightening, You mean our Unit of Work which actually does commit operation will handle transactions by default?

Comment: @AirCodeOne there's no `RemoveRanges`. There's no need for transactions with EF or NHibernate. The "repository" code you used broke EF. We can't tell you how to fix code you didn't post, but the real solution is to simply remove the "generic repository" code. Read carefully [There is no need for Unit of Work or Repository with Entity Framework](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the reference will refer to this and post solution if works. Thanks

Comment: A DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is already a repository. A DbContext persists all changes and only connects to the database to load data or persist changes with `SaveChanges`. When you call `SaveChanges` it persists **all** pending changes, not just the last one. The only reason you may need to use an explicit transaction is you put a low-level "repository" interface on top of the high-level DbContext, executing `SaveChanges` after every single operation. That broke Unit-of-Work so now you need an extra transaction to bring it back

Comment: @AirCodeOne there's no "if works". EF works, when used properly. Why do you think no documentation tutorial uses the "repository" pattern? Didn't Microsoft know about it? MS has been publishing pattern guides for 20 years, even provided repo implementations *before* it became unnecessary. Why are so many EF-related questions about *"repository"*-induced problems? Generic repositories and ORMs are a square peg for a round hole

Comment: @AirCodeOne this is **nothing new either** [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) was written in 2009. Unfortunately, some "boilerplate" frameworks and lazy writers simply copy-pasted Java techniques so they could say they cover "best practices".That generic repo does a lot more than break UoW though - it breaks the disconnected operation and optimistic concurrency of DbContext, forcing long-lived transactions, causing blocks and deadlocks. By using it, you're back to 1999, when disconnected recordsets were introduced

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I really appreciate your response, This really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the implementation of your associated implementation code for your Unit of Work and Repository and folks should be able to assist. There is nothing wrong with using an abstraction in front of your data access code, just as you should be putting abstractions between your UI code and other volatile dependencies. However, you do need to have a good understanding of how the underlying implementation code works, especially if you're going to stack multiple abstractions on top of it (e.g. unit of work, repository).

What does GetConditionalQuery look like?
What does RemoveRange look like?
What does _unitOfWork look like and where is it started or otherwise referenced?

Given a bit more context, it's probably possible to get your implementation working as desired. If you're looking for Microsoft guidance demonstrating how to use repositories within architecture, look here:

- https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design

Why don't the EF docs include a bunch of repositories in them? Because a repository is an application abstraction, not an implementation. EF is an implementation. It's not their responsibility to determine how or whether you choose to use abstractions between your app and its dependencies. So, the absence of repository pattern usage in EF docs is not evidence they don't recommend the pattern. Ultimately I suggest they would prefer folks just use their library directly, as it makes their lives easier, but they're not responsible for maintaining your app.

More on the general repository-or-not debate (which is really an abstractions-or-not debate, which is really a SOLID-or-not debate):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbYYz5i_B_Y&ab_channel=weeklydevtips
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-O_WVzkLtAA&ab_channel=weeklydevtips
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eICIBt5rkw&ab_channel=weeklydevtips

Good luck!